# Javascript form issue

Tags: javascript

I just wanted to know why document.form1.from_date.value = ""; doesn't work. And this is the form code for date from

```
<td style="border:0px !important;"><span class="mytxtLabel" style="float:left"> Created From Date</span></td>
<td style="border:0px !important;"><input type="text" name="from_date" style="z-index:20002;width:160px !important;" value="<?=$D1?>" id="from_date" placeholder='From Date' /></td>.
```

THanks

Comment: what is `form1` - does not appear in any of your html

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/483ropu5/  Do you have any code which actually demonstrates a problem of some kind?

Comment: can you provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   ???

Answer (score 0):

This will Help you.

**Without Form element**

```js
document.getElementById('from_date').value = "";
```

```html
<td style="border:0px !important;"><span class="mytxtLabel" style="float:left"> Created From Date</span></td> <td style="border:0px !important;"><input type="text" name="from_date" style="z-index:20002;width:160px !important;" value="<?=$D1?>" id="from_date" placeholder='From Date'/></td>
```

**With Form element**

```js
document.form1.from_date.value = ""
```

```html
<form name="form1">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td style="border:0px !important;">
    <span class="mytxtLabel" style="float:left"> Created From Date</span>
   </td>
   <td style="border:0px !important;">
    <input type="text" name="from_date" style="z-index:20002;width:160px !important;" value="<?=$D1?>" id="from_date" placeholder='From Date' />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```